# Comprimindo e organizando Json

Tags: json, otimização

Venho estudando Json recentemente para utilizar nos meus projetos para substituir banco de dados em alguns casos, nos meus testes encontrei uma duvida. dependendo do projeto eu posso acabar repetindo alguns valores em certos itens varias vezes durante o código por exemplo

```html
[
  {
    "Empresa"       : "Unimed",
    "Categoria"     : "Hospital",
    "Tags"          : ["Plano de saude" , "Clinicas diversas", "Venda de serviços" ],
    "Endereco"      : "Rua Fulano de Tal",
    "IconeEmpresa"  : "icone.png",
    "IconeCategoria": "hospital.png"
  },
  {
    "Empresa"       : "Ipiranga",
    "Categoria"     : "Posto de gasolina",
    "Tags"          : ["Venda de Produtos", "Venda de serviços" ],
    "Endereco"      : "Rua Fulano",
    "IconeEmpresa"  : "icone2.png",
    "IconeCategoria": "posto.png"
  },
  {
    "Empresa"       : "Beneficente",
    "Categoria"     : "Hospital",
    "Tags"          : ["Plano de saude" , "Venda de serviços" ,"Medico Especializado"],
    "Endereco"      : "Rua Almirante Jequitir",
    "IconeEmpresa"  : "icone3.png",
    "IconeCategoria": "hospital.png"
  },
  {
    "Empresa"       : "FarmaBem",
    "Categoria"     : "Farmacia",
    "Tags"          : [ "Venda de serviços" ],
    "Endereco"      : "Rua Sicranol",
    "IconeEmpresa"  : "icone4.png",
    "IconeCategoria": "farmacia.png"
  }
]
```

Neste caso por exemplo o item "Categoria" tem um limite na possibilidades de de valor (neste exemplo coloquei 3 valores, Hospital, Posto de gasolina e Farmacia, caso eu fosse inserir um novo registro deveria adicionar uma dessas 3 categorias já existente provocando a repetição) alem disso a "Categoria" estar direta ligada ao "IconeCategoria" sendo que cada categoria possui um único ícone correspondente.

Minha duvida e se existe um modo de otimizar esses itens, para não ocorrer o risco de por algum erro ser inserido uma categoria com o nome diferente (tipo hospital ao invés de Hospital) ou no caso de ter que alterá a logica ou o nome de alguma categoria futuramente precisar alterá linha por linha (Exemplo, no futuro pode ser necessário unificar a "Categoria" Hospital e Farmacia criando uma nova "Categoria" Saude).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A minha solução foi criar um dicionário com as categorias, assim você não precisa encher o objeto empresa com atributos que pertencem a `categoria`:

```js
var categorias = {
    Hospital:{
      descricao: "Hospital",
      icone:"hospital.png"
    },
    PostoDeGasolina:{
      descricao: "Posto de Gasolina",
      icone:"posto.png"
    },
    Farmacia:{
      descricao: "Farmácia",
      icone:"farmacia.png"
    }
};
```

Caso você precise adicionar uma nova categoria, basta inserir um novo objeto de categoria no dicionário categorias com suas respectivas propriedades dentro.
Já na construção do objeto `empresa` no atributo `Categoria` basta passar um dos objetos existentes dentro do dicionário de categorias.

Segue um teste prático de como funciona, qualquer duvida estou a disposição.

```js
var categorias = {
    Hospital:{
      descricao: "Hospital",
      icone:"hospital.png"
    },
    PostoDeGasolina:{
      descricao: "Posto de Gasolina",
      icone:"posto.png"
    },
    Farmacia:{
      descricao: "Farmácia",
      icone:"farmacia.png"
    },
};

var empresas = [
  {
    Empresa       : "Unimed",
    Categoria     : categorias.Hospital,
    Tags          : ["Plano de saude" , "Clinicas diversas", "Venda de serviços" ],
    Endereco      : "Rua Fulano de Tal",
    IconeEmpresa  : "icone.png",
  },
  {
    Empresa       : "Ipiranga",
    Categoria     : categorias.PostoDeGasolina,
    Tags          : ["Venda de Produtos", "Venda de serviços" ],
    Endereco      : "Rua Fulano",
    IconeEmpresa  : "icone2.png",
  },
  {
    Empresa       : "Beneficente",
    Categoria     : categorias.Hospital,
    Tags          : ["Plano de saude" , "Venda de serviços" ,"Medico Especializado"],
    Endereco      : "Rua Almirante Jequitir",
    IconeEmpresa  : "icone3.png",
  },
  {
    Empresa       : "FarmaBem",
    Categoria     : categorias.Farmacia,
    Tags          : [ "Venda de serviços" ],
    Endereco      : "Rua Sicranol",
    IconeEmpresa  : "icone4.png",
  }
];

var i =0;
for(i = 0; i < empresas.length; i ++){
  console.log(empresas[i].Categoria.descricao);
}
```

Comment: Mas assim está aumentando o tamanho do arquivo repetindo esses valores (categorias.Hospital), substitui isso (categorias.Hospital) por um ID numérico e adiciona um ID no dicionário, e quando for exibir a informação leia o dicionário pelo ID.

Comment: não entendi for no final, no caso estou mexendo apenas com o json sem javascript pois quem lerá o arquivo seria um sistema Java ou Android. Mas a ideia de construir um dicionario realmente abre os horizontes, juntando com a ideia do @CarlosFagianiJr do substituir (categarias.Hospital) por um ID sem duvida deve resolver meu problema

Comment: Eu acho que a ideia do Carlos não tem lógica, pois o programador vai ficar perdido, eu ficaria, a não ser que esse ID viesse de um banco de dados. O for no final foi um exemplo de como acessar os dados. Mas de qualquer forma fico feliz em ter resolvido :D

Comment: @CarlosFagianiJr como você saberia que o ID == 1 é Hospital?

Comment: Eu entendi a pergunta errado, pensei que ele queria reduzir o tamanho do JSON, mas ele queria era somente organizar os dados, a tua resposta está certa. Do jeito que eu sugeri seria assim: https://jsfiddle.net/u2zdwsxm/